# AWS Cognito - How do I resend an email confirmation code?

Tags: amazon-cognito

What happens when an email confirmation code expires? From documentation, it expires after 24hrs. What if the user lost the code somehow, can I let users resend the codes for themselves?

Comment: Yes, if you are using Amplify, you can use Auth.resendSignUp()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Nghia Do in the comments above, you can use Auth.resendSignup(username) if you are using Amplify.

Answer (score 2):

For flutter, simply do this:

`var response = await Amplify.Auth.resendSignUpCode(username: username);`